# How can I log from my python application to splunk, if I use celery as my task scheduler?

Tags: python, logging, celery, splunk

I have a python script running on a server, that should get executed once a day by the celery scheduler. I want to send my logs directly from the script to splunk. I am trying to use this [splunk_handler](https://github.com/zach-taylor/splunk_handler) library. If I run the splunk_handler without celery locally, it seems to work. But if I run it together with celery there seem to be no logs that reach the splunk_handler. Console-Log:

> [SplunkHandler DEBUG] Timer thread executed but no payload was available to send

How do I set up the loggers correctly, so that all the logs go to the splunk_handler?

Apparently, celery sets up its own loggers and overwrites the root-logger from python. I tried several things, including connecting the setup_logging signal from celery to prevent it to overwrite the loggers or setting up the logger in this signal.

```
import logging
import os

from splunk_handler import SplunkHandler
```

This is how I set up the logger at the beginning of the file

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
splunk_handler = SplunkHandler(
host=os.getenv('SPLUNK_HTTP_COLLECTOR_URL'),
port=os.getenv('SPLUNK_HTTP_COLLECTOR_PORT'),
token=os.getenv('SPLUNK_TOKEN'),
index=os.getenv('SPLUNK_INDEX'),
debug=True)

splunk_handler.setFormatter(logging.BASIC_FORMAT)
splunk_handler.setLevel(os.getenv('LOGGING_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'))
logger.addHandler(splunk_handler)
```

Celery initialisation (not sure, if `worker_hijack_root_logger` needs to be set to `False`...)

```
app = Celery('name_of_the_application', broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL)
app.conf.timezone = 'Europe/Berlin'
app.conf.update({
    'worker_hijack_root_logger': False,
})
```

Here I connect to the setup_logging signal from celery

```
@setup_logging.connect()
def config_loggers(*args, **kwags):
    pass
    # logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    # splunk_handler = SplunkHandler(
    #     host=os.getenv('SPLUNK_HTTP_COLLECTOR_URL'),
    #     port=os.getenv('SPLUNK_HTTP_COLLECTOR_PORT'),
    #     token=os.getenv('SPLUNK_TOKEN'),
    #     index=os.getenv('SPLUNK_INDEX'),
    #     debug=True)
    #
    # splunk_handler.setFormatter(logging.BASIC_FORMAT)
    # splunk_handler.setLevel(os.getenv('LOGGING_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'))
    # logger.addHandler(splunk_handler)
```

Log statement

```
logger.info("ARBITRARY LOG MESSAGE")
```

When activating debug on splunk handler (set to `True`), the splunk handler logs out that there is no payload available as already posted above. Does anybody have an idea what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of figuring out what eventually could be wrong with my code, I now have a result that satisfies me. First I created a file `loggingsetup.py` where I configured my python loggers with dictConfig:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': { # Sets up the format of the logging output
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
             'datefmt': '%y %b %d, %H:%M:%S',
            },
        },
    'filters': {
        'filterForSplunk': { # custom loggingFilter, to not have Logs logged to Splunk that have the word celery in the name
            '()': 'loggingsetup.RemoveCeleryLogs', # class on top of this file
            'logsToSkip': 'celery' # word that it is filtered for
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'splunk': { # handler for splunk, level Warning. to not have many logs sent to splunk
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'splunk_logging_handler.SplunkLoggingHandler',
            'url': os.getenv('SPLUNK_HTTP_COLLECTOR_URL'),
            'splunk_key': os.getenv('SPLUNK_TOKEN'),
            'splunk_index': os.getenv('SPLUNK_INDEX'),
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'filters': ['filterForSplunk']
        },
        'console': { 
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
    },
    'loggers': { # the logger, root is used
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'splunk'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': 'False', # does not give logs to other logers
        }
    }
}
```

For the logging filter, I had to create a class that inherits from the logging.Filter class. The class also relies in file `loggingsetup.py`

```
class RemoveCeleryLogs(logging.Filter): # custom class to filter for celery logs (to not send them to Splunk)
    def __init__(self, logsToSkip=None):
        self.logsToSkip = logsToSkip

    def filter(self, record):
        if self.logsToSkip == None:
            allow = True
        else:
            allow = self.logsToSkip not in record.name
        return allow
```

After that, you can configer the loggers like this:

```
logging.config.dictConfig(loggingsetup.LOGGING)
logger = logging.getLogger('')
```

And because celery redirected it's logs and logs were doubled, I had to update the app.conf:

```
app.conf.update({
    'worker_hijack_root_logger': False, # so celery does not set up its loggers
    'worker_redirect_stdouts': False, # so celery does not redirect its logs
})
```

The next Problem I was facing was, that my chosen Splunk_Logging library mixed something up with the url. So I had to create my own splunk_handler class that inherits from the logging.Handler class. The important lines here are the following (from my custom logger class splunk_logging_class.py):

```
auth_header = {'Authorization': 'Splunk {0}'.format(self.splunk_key)}
json_message = {"index": str(self.splunk_index), "event": data}
r = requests.post(self.url, headers=auth_header, json=json_message)
```

I hope that I can help someone with this answer who is facing similar problems with python, splunk and celery logging! :)

Comment: thanks, used the same approach to setup GCP Logger

Comment: Where does `splunk_logging_handler.SplunkLoggingHandler` come from?

Comment: As written in the last section of the solution the initial Splunk Logging Handler Library did not work in my case (something wrong with the header). So this "splunk_logging_handler" is a custom splunk logging Class.