# Unable to push Celery task logs to Google Cloud (stackdriver)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, celery, google-cloud-stackdriver, python-logging

I'm trying to push celery task logs to GCP using their Logging API. I'm using **google.cloud.logging.handlers.CloudLoggingHandler** for the same.

Here is how I'm doing it:

settings.py

```
from google.cloud import logging as gcp_logging
gcp_client = gcp_logging.Client()
gcp_client.setup_logging()
LOGGING_FOLDER = ''
LOG_NAME = 'custom-logs'
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'gcp_log': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'google.cloud.logging.handlers.CloudLoggingHandler',
            'client': gcp_client,
            'name': LOG_NAME,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'celery': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(LOGGING_FOLDER, 'celery.log'),
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 100,  # 100 MB
            'backupCount': 15,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'myapp.tasks':{
            'handlers': ['celery', 'gcp_log'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True
        },
        'celery.worker':{
            'handlers': ['celery', 'gcp_log'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False
        },
    },
}
```

myapp/tasks.py

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
@task
def add(x, y):
    print("Add - I am from Print ")
    logger.info("Add - I am from logger")
    return x + y
```

All the logs, appear in celery handler i.e. celery.log file but only worker logs appear on GCP. **myapp.tasks** logs doesn't get uploaded to GCP.

My app is currently django based but I've also  tried it in vanilla Python. Still the same behaviour.

I followed the method 1 described in https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/08/28/celery-logging/  but it also yielded same results. Is there any configuration miss I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem a few weeks ago but with logging to splunk. Here is my answer: [How can I log from my python application to splunk, if I use celery as my task scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144150/how-can-i-log-from-my-python-application-to-splunk-if-i-use-celery-as-my-task-s)

I think that the problem could be where you set:

```
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
```

This might generate a logger that is not mentioned in the settings.py file. Maybe grab a logger that you specificaly set up in your settings.py file with its handlers. 
But I personnaly just set up my own logger like you can see in my linked answer from above. I hope this might help yuo a bit...